# Many ASP.NET Projects - One shared tools library - how to avoid recompiling?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Am I doing this right?  I've got many, many separate ASP.NET webforms projects which reference the same main library which contains many tool methods.  When I change something in that library, I don't know of a way to make sure that these projects get the updated version of the library.  Does auto-refresh detect changes in references even if you don't open the project in Visual Studio?  Or does IIS know when a reference has changed and will recompile the project?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the DLL file is binary compatible (changing an existing method signature is the easiest way to break compatibility) all it comes down is that the newest DLL is in the `\bin\` folder. If the site is running it would need to be restarted to pick up the DLL being replaced.

If this is a project reference in your solution, building just does all of this for you.

If this project is outside of your solution, you really should look into using [Nuget](http://www.nuget.org) to distribute this shared project. Even if you only distribute it to yourself. You do not need to host the package publicly on nuget.org